# mod_rewrite doesn't work

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

The url is *`localhost/testing`* and I have 2 files one is *`bad.html`* and the second is *`good.html`* (Both just display a message).

The *`.htaccess`* file I have in that folder :

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* good.html
```

If I run `phpinfo();` I see in "Loaded Modules" the mod_rewrite.
I use ubuntu 12.04 and the folder *`/etc/apache2/mods-available`* includes `rewrite.load` file.

Should't that directives I use in `.htaccess` when I go to *`localhost/testing/bad.html`* redirects me to *`localhost/testing/good.html`* ?

Comment: More likely, this is going to cause a rewrite loop. Does it not give you a 500 error?

Comment: no it just open the bad.html, guess that means mod_rewrite is not enabled?